# Check jCheckBox1, uncheck jCheckBox2

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I have two checkboxes placed on form. If user set check on checkbox1 than uncheck checkbox2 and vice versa.

```
chRISING0 = new JCheckBox("RISING");
    chRISING0.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                chFR0.setSelected(false);
        }
    });
    chRISING0.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 9));
    chRISING0.setBounds(42, 15, 84, 23);
    pnlOUT1.add(chRISING0);


chFR0 = new JCheckBox(fpp.loadLanguage("chFR0"));
    chFR0.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 9));
    chFR0.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {               
            chRISING0.setSelected(false);
        }
    });
    chFR0.setBounds(42, 35, 67, 23);
    pnlOUT1.add(chFR0);
```

Strange problem happens when I check chRISING0 and move mouse on chFR0. Than chRISING0 unchecks even I didn't press on chFR0. 
Why? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you use radio button instead of checkbox?

Comment: Unfortunately the requirement is checkbox :(

Answer (score 5):

It would be easier if you used a [`ButtonGroup`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html#method.summary). See [How to Use the ButtonGroup Component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html) for details.

Comment: Nice one! This is the correct approach for the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I confused two listeners in my previous answer (I didn't code the swing for a while). You must use ItemListener because it is responsible for an on/off changes.

```
chRISING0.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            chFR0.setSelected(false);
    }
});
chFR0.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {               
        chRISING0.setSelected(false);
    }
});
```

**DEPRECATED:**

```
chRISING0.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            chFR0.setSelected(false);
    }
});
```

*You're using ItemListener. Try using ChangeListener as you did with second CheckBox.*

```
chRISING0.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            chFR0.setSelected(false);
    }
});
chFR0.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {               
        chRISING0.setSelected(false);
    }
});
```

*ItemListener reacts to a components state change (state changes when you hover a mouse over the component or click on it) unlike ChangeListener.*